# Impact of (server-side) Prepared Statements on a MySQL 5.5+ Query Plan

Tags: mysql, performance

So, since cursory googling doesn't reveal anything enlightening:

How does MySQL generate a query plan for a Prepared Statement such as the server-side ones implemented in Connector/J for JDBC? Specifically, does it generate it at the time that the SQL statement is compiled and then reuse it with every execution regardless of the parameters or will it actually adjust the plan in the same manner that would be achieved with issuing each SQL query separately?

If it does happen to be "smart" about it, an explanation of how it does this would be great (e.g. variable peeking)

Comment: Are you asking for a `SELECT` type of query or?

Comment: Does it matter? Any query with some sort of lookup needs a query plan.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases, the query plan is built when you execute the statement.  In MySQL (unlike competing products), building the plan is very fast, so you don't really need to worry about whether it is cached in any way.

Also, but building as needed, different values in the query can lead to different query plans, hence faster execution.

(In the extreme, I have seen one statement, with different constants, have 6 different query plans.)

Comment: When you say "one statement" -  are you referring to a statement that is pre-compiled as a prepared statement or the human-readable SQL being sent to the server every time for execution? My question specifically pertains to server-side caching of an SQL statement.

Comment: I don't think there is any server-side caching, except maybe in Stored Routines (that are compiled once per connection).

Comment: See the `useServerPrepStmts` option in Connector/J for MySQL.